# Mathematics Audiobooks for the Blind?

Tags: book-recommendation

Are there any mathematics audiobooks, such as for those who are blind? How do they pronounce the equations?

Comment: Audio books for the deaf? You mean like movies for the blind?

Comment: @GitGud: Yeah, I was actually thinking about mathematical braille when I was writing the question… thanks for the correction.

Comment: this question made me wonder how difficult it is for the blind to understand mathematics ._.

Comment: @Lucyfer Zedd: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889594/who-are-some-blind-or-otherwise-disabled-mathematicians-who-have-made-important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find the answers to [**this post**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35496/is-there-a-definitive-guide-to-speaking-mathematics) helpful, in terms of standards for speaking mathematics without relying on the receiver's vision.

The question asks for a definitive guide to *spoken* mathematics. You'll find many resources there, including the link to [*Handbook for Spoken Mathmatics*](http://s22318.tsbvi.edu/mathproject/appB-sec1.asp#main).

Answer (score 0):

Lectures on mathematics ([e.g. MIT courses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbIQW0gkgxo)) can be considered as audio-books of mathematics.